# Calculate SUM of associative and echo to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a page with 9 different select lists. I want to use query if possible to calculate & display the SUM (price), based on the selections chosen. I would ideally like the price to autoupdate as list items are selected.  The first challenge is that the select options do not have prices in the id, value or text.  I thought a good way to handle that issue would be to associate the ids with prices by using an associative array.  The second challenge is that the id tags (for almost all of the options) contain dashes, not underscores.  Dashes are seen as subtraction in javascript and query, that is not going to work.  Here is the code I have created so far. I do not know how to make it calculate a sum, using this type of array, then display it in to a div.

I am open to suggestions if anyone has a better, or easier way?

shortened example of a select list:

```
<select id="pa_handle-knob">
<option value="s9-c-cork-knobs">some text here</ far.option>
<option value="s9-eva-eva-tech-knobs">some text here</option>
</select>
```

Example array and calculation script so far:

```
(function($) {
var pa_handle_knob_caps = $("[id='pa_handle-knob-caps']"){
  "brushed-silver": "4.5",
    "lime": "5",
    'black': '4.5',
    'blue-2': '4.25',
    'gold': '4.5',
    'silver': '4.5',
    'red-2': '4.5',
    'purple': '4.5',
    'yellow': '4.5',
    'gunsmoke': '4.5',
    'matte-black': '4.5'
}

var pa_handle_knob = $("[id='pa_handle-knob']"){
    'ts9-c-cork-knobs': '1',
    'ts9-eva-eva-tech-knobs': '3'

}

var pa_line_guide_cap = $("[id='pa_line-guide-cap']"){
  'brushed-silver-guide-cap': '3.25',
    'lime-guide-cap': '3.25',
    'black-guide-cap': '3.25',
    'blue-guide-cap': '3.25',
    'gold-guide-cap': '3.25',
    'silver-guide-cap': '3.25',
    'red-guide-cap': '3.25',
    'purple-guide-cap': '3.25',
    'yellow-guide-cap': '3.25',
    'gunsmoke-guide-cap': '3.25',
    'matte-black-guide-cap': '3.25'
}
 $("#pa_handle-knob-caps").change(function() {
  calc_and_total();
})
$("#pa_handle-knob").change(function() {
  calc_and_total();
})
$("#pa_line-guide-cap").change(function() {
  calc_and_total();
})

    function calc_and_total(pa_handle_knob_caps, pa_handle_knob, pa_line_guide_cap) {
  var add = parseFloat(pa_handle_knob_caps) + parseFloat(pa_handle_knob) + parseFloat(pa_line_guide_cap);

  add += parseFloat(this.value, 10);
}) $('#result').html('The sum of the selected text options - ' +add);
});
```

Comment: Well, there's a lot of things wrong with your code, and I'm not an expert with these associative arrays, but I can start by telling you that you're referring to a function called `calc_and_SHOW_total` but you're defining a function called `calc_and_total` (without the word 'show'). That for sure will mess up some things :). Good luck!

Comment: What are you trying to do with $("[id='pa_handle-knob-caps']"){ .... }?